# Create a function factory in R from a given function instead of a typed function

Tags: r, function, factory

Usually in R one can create a function factory by writing the code of the "mother" function inside. But I want to use an already defined function as the "mother" function.

I do the following:

```r
#
# typical way of creating a function factory:
#
power_factory <- function(exp) {
  function(x) {
    x ^ exp
  }
}
square <- power_factory(2)

rlang::env_print(square)
#> <environment: 0x7fae8900f3b8>
#> parent: <environment: global>
#> bindings:
#>  * exp: <lazy>

rlang::fn_env(square)$exp
#> [1] 2


#
# but I need to do this from an already defined "mother" function:
#
mother_fun <- function(x) {
  x ^ exp
}
power_factory <- function(exp) {
  mother_fun
}
square <- power_factory(2)

rlang::env_print(square)
#> <environment: global>
#> parent: <environment: package:rlang>
#> bindings:
#>  * power_factory: <fn>
#>  * mother_fun: <fn>
#>  * .Random.seed: <int>
#>  * square: <fn>

rlang::fn_env(square)$exp
#> NULL
```

Obviously one cannot directly include the variable containing the mother function (i.e., mother_fun) like I did above as the variable exp does not get binded. I have tried many things in the context of metaprogramming trying to use expressions and quasiquotations, but without success. Any help would be welcomed! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (as long as the function is a closure and not a primitive function):

```
mother_fun <- function(x) {
  x ^ exp
}

environment(mother_fun) <- new.env()
environment(mother_fun)$exp <- 2

mother_fun(3)
#[1] 9
```